# Sequencing a custom action in WiX before "LaunchConditions"

Tags: wix, custom-action, launch-condition

Is it possible to sequence a custom action before "LaunchConditions"?

This is my custom action:

```
<CustomAction
    Id="CA_vcAppRunning"
    BinaryKey="vcShowMsg"
    DllEntry="IsAppRunning"
    Return="check"
    Execute="immediate"/>
```

Sequenced in `<InstallExecuteSequence/>`

```
<Custom Action="CA_vcAppRunning" Before="LaunchConditions" />
```

I tried this, opened the MSI file in [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and found that my custom action is sequenced at "99".
But when I tried to install, it never got called.

I want to schedule this before LaunchConditions as this custom action is supposed to set a property which is used in the LaunchCondition (if the application is running, exit the installer/updater).

Answer (score 4):

Don't schedule it in before `LaunchConditions`, schedule it after `FindRelatedProducts` and then add a second custom action that blocks install based on the results from your first CA.

This is the same method used to prevent downgrading in many tutorials, e.g.

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_BlockOlderVersionInstall" Error="!(loc.LaunchCondition_LaterVersion)" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
        <LaunchConditions After="AppSearch" />
        <Custom Action="CA_BlockOlderVersionInstall" After="FindRelatedProducts">
            <![CDATA[NEWERVERSIONDETECTED]]>
        </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<InstallUISequence>
        <LaunchConditions After="AppSearch" />
        <Custom Action="CA_BlockOlderVersionInstall" After="FindRelatedProducts">
            <![CDATA[NEWERVERSIONDETECTED]]>
        </Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

Comment: My custom action had to be changed to `Execute="immediate"` instead of `defered` otherwise I get a "error code is 2762" and only works during after InstallInitialize and before AfterInstall.